# Reduce game size in Cocos Creator cocos2d-x

Tags: android, ios, cocos2d-x, cocos2d-js, cocoscreator

I am developing a game using **Cocos Creator for Android and iOS platforms**. The game is small in scale and has few graphics elements.

I found that the APK and IPA file size for this game is **11.5 MB**. I think these files (APK or IPA) must be containing some unnecessary files. The Asset folder's size is just 5 MB.

I have following questions:

1. How to **reduce the game size for iOS and Android** platform in Cocos Creator?
2. Are there any optimization techniques for **reducing size of art assets** (without affecting quality)?

I would appreciate any suggestions/thoughts on this topic. Thank you.

Comment: Watch [this](http://discuss.cocos2d-x.org/t/how-to-reduce-the-final-build-size-of-a-cocos2dx-project/32875/2)

Answer (score 3):

I've never worked with Cocos Creator, but having a couple of commercial game development experiment, The size of game is almost the size of its assets.

Assets includes images and sounds. For images:

1. If you don't need alpha channel, avoid `.png`.
2. Try [this awesome service](https://tinypng.com/) to reduce your `.png` files. It saved me 70% !
3. FYI, `sprite sheet` has nothing with game size. It improve the memory usage.
4. You can also check [this](https://realm.io/news/reducing-apk-size-native-libraries) link.

I also recommend [this](http://www.learn-cocos2d.com/2012/11/optimize-memory-usage-bundle-size-cocos2d-app/) if you try to improve your memory usage as well.

Answer (score 1):

In cocos creator, you can remove none used components.
Before you  build cocos creator projects, click "Project" Menu, select "Module Config", Here you can deselect components which you don't use in you game.
Hope this can help you!